# What could suddenly turn off PHP-FPM?

Tags: nginx, php

I have a website with NGINX & PHP-FPM. A few hours ago I checked my website and NGINX throw an error. My website was down.

I check the status pages of NGINX and the fpm pool, and the fpm status page did not load.
Then I checked the status of PHP-FPM with "service php5-fpm status" and it showed that it wasn't running. So I restarted it.

Right now everything is fine, and commonly nothing wrong happens, but now I want to know what could possibly turn off php-fpm? Could it be a script? A memory problem? Is it a common practice to have a script controlling that PHP-FPM is running?

Thanks you!

Answer (score 1):

Who knows, this is why us sysadmins install monitoring solutions and 24hour text notifications, and install things like puppet and template it to ensure certain services are always running... You'll get a more detailed answer on www.serverfault.com - this is a programming site.

Comment: Thanks Skrilled, I post it here because I thought that maybe certain programming stuff could also affect php-fpm (also stackoverflow is more popular and you can get answers quickly).

Answer (score 1):

Probably a segmentation fault in a php child. Do your php-fpm logs show segmentation faults or other errors?

Yes, it's common practice to have a service running that checks to make sure php-fpm and other services are running.

Comment: Thanks @Avibodha I'm going attach my php-fpm log. Anyway, when the problem occurred I check the php-fpm log and I didn't found anything special. No errors apparently, also until now it's working fine since I restarted.

Comment: seg faults may be in system log /var/log/messages or equivalent